# Why does the controller display questions instead of Cyrillic characters?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, encoding

I can’t send Russian letters to the server in any way, the server is constantly receiving "???????".

Here is my Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateCustomerInfo", produces ="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        @ResponseBody
        public void updateCustomerInfo(@RequestHeader(name = "id") HashMap<String,String> map){
            new CustomerManager().updateCustomerInfo(map.get("uuid"),
                    map.get("first_name"),
                    map.get("middle_name"),
                    map.get("last_name"),
                    map.get("phone"),
                    map.get("email"),
                    Boolean.parseBoolean(map.get("email_notification")),
                    map.get("adress"));
            System.out.println(map.get("first_name"));
        }
```

I tried to add a filter to my web.xml, but that didn't help either: web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebAppId" version="3.0"
>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/controller-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

What else can you try, tell me please!

Client(Android volley) :

public void updateCustomerInfo(final String uuid, final String first_name,

final String middle_name, final String last_name, final String phone, final

String email, final boolean email_notification, final String adress){

JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT,

"http://10.0.2.2:8080/updateCustomerInfo", null, new

Response.Listener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                map.put("uuid",uuid);
                map.put("first_name",first_name);
                map.put("middle_name",middle_name);
                map.put("last_name",last_name);
                map.put("phone",phone);
                map.put("email",email);
                map.put("email_notification",String.valueOf(email_notification));
                map.put("adress",adress);
                return map;
            }
        };
        VolleyQueue.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(objectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: How do you compose request's header section on client side?

Comment: Did you try by adding `consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"`

Comment: Both the *produces* and *consumes* annotation are conditions to decide what method will handle the request. None of them influence the character encoding in any way. Only the content type is relevant. The encoding suffix is ignored in both annotations.

Comment: consumes not help me:(. Im add to main message my client call @aka-one